# How to bold text with **text** in String

Tags: android, string-formatting, spannablestring

I want to bold text in between of **. I have tried with following code but no success. It is creating whole text bold.

> Original String : **Hi**, My Name is **XYZ** with **PQR**"
>
> Want Output : **Hi**, My Name is **XYZ** with **PQR**

This is what I have tried.

```
private SpannableStringBuilder getText() {
    String message = "**Hi**, My Name is **XYZ** with **PQR**";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+.+(.*?).+.+");
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(message);

    SpannableStringBuilder spannable = new SpannableStringBuilder(message);
    StyleSpan span = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        spannable.setSpan(span, matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
    return spannable;
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is in your regular expression: ".+.+(.*?).+.+". What you're saying here is: any chacacter, followed by any character, followed by any occourrence of any character, followed twice by any character. This will match to the whole string. So the question is: what part of your string should be in bold?

Comment: @GregorioPalamà **** in between of **inBold**

Comment: Your regular expression needs to escape the asterisk (`*`) character so that it is treated as something to be matched, and not as the quantifier that means 0 or more occurrences of something. Once you have the correct pattern, the span should make the relevant areas bold.

Comment: @TheGamer007 Can you provide correct regular expression.

Comment: In the future, you can use sites like regex101.com for testing expressions. Based on a quick try, `(\*\*).*?(\*\*)` seems to be working. The `\*` refers to the literal asterisk symbol. So I'm checking if any number of characters are between a pair of double asterisks. Based on how you want to constrain the middle group though, the expression would have to be modified. Ex: No empty middle

Comment: Another thing you'll need to take care of is removing the asterisk symbols, and only showing the text they enclose.

Comment: @TheGamer007 can we remove this from regex or i need to use replace function of String

Comment: Posted as an answer to avoid discussion in question comments. Please comment any other queries there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex pattern is using the `*` symbol without escaping it. Thus, it is treated as a quantifier and not a character to be matched. Fixing the expression should let the rest of your code work as intended. To test patterns, you can use sites like [regex101.com](https://www.regex101.com)

While I haven't tested this extensively, the following pattern is a basic one that fits your needs: `(\*\*)(.*?)(\*\*)`

This allows you to match the substrings "**Hi**", "**XYZ**" and "**PQR**". Your code currently bolds these in their entirety. What you probably want to do is remove the asterisks and insert the middle text in bold.

As per my pattern, your text should be available as the second matched group. So you can extract indices from that to apply the span, and remove all `**` occurrences from it. There should be methods in both the String and regex classes that can be used for this.

Based on your exact needs, you'd have different constraints and edge cases, like what to do with "****" where the middle text is empty.

Answer (score 3):

Please use this code for solving above problem

```
 private SpannableStringBuilder getActivityText(String message) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\*\\*)(.*?)(\\*\\*)");
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(message);

    SpannableStringBuilder spannable = new SpannableStringBuilder(message);
    List<StyleSpan> spans = new ArrayList<>();
    //for making text bold
    while (matcher.find()) {
        StyleSpan span = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
        spannable.setSpan(span, matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        spans.add(span);
    }
    //for removing ** text
    for (StyleSpan span : spans) {
        spannable.replace(spannable.getSpanStart(span), spannable.getSpanStart(span) + 2, "");
        spannable.replace(spannable.getSpanEnd(span) - 2, spannable.getSpanEnd(span), "");
    }

    return spannable;
}
```